# Why doesn't the pop up close when opened from inside an UpdatePanel

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, gridview

JQuery (inside the head function in my webform):

```
function DoThisEM() {
    centerPopupEM();
    loadPopupEM();
}

function DoThatEM() {
    disablePopupEM();
}
var popupStatusEM = 0;
//loading popup with jQuery magic!
function loadPopupEM() {
    //loads popup only if it is disabled
    if (popupStatusEM == 0) {
        $("#backgroundPopupEM").css({
            "opacity": "0.7"
        });
        $("#backgroundPopupEM").fadeIn("slow");
        $("#popupContactEM").fadeIn("slow");
        popupStatusEM = 1;
    }
}
//disabling popup with jQuery magic!
function disablePopupEM() {
    //disables popup only if it is enabled
    if (popupStatusEM == 1) {
        $("#backgroundPopupEM").fadeOut("slow");
        $("#popupContactEM").fadeOut("slow");
        popupStatusEM = 0;
    }
}
//centering popup
function centerPopupEM() {
    //request data for centering
    var windowWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
    var windowHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
    var popupHeight = $("#popupContactEM").height();
    var popupWidth = $("#popupContactEM").width();
    //centering
    $("#popupContactEM").css({
        "position": "absolute",
        "top": windowHeight / 2 - popupHeight / 2,
        "left": windowWidth / 2 - popupWidth / 2
    });
    //only need force for IE6

    $("#backgroundPopupEM").css({
        "height": windowHeight
    });
}

$("body").on('click', "#popupContactCloseEM", function (e) {
    //e.preventDefault();
    alert('popupContactCloseEM');
    disablePopupEM();
});
$("body").on('click', "#backgroundPopupEM", function (e) {
    //e.preventDefault();
    alert('backgroundPopupEM');
    disablePopupEM();
});
```

GridView:

[image]

Popup (when clicked on any of the `edit` icon:

[image]

I am not sure why but when I click on the `x` or the background around the popup, the `disablePopupEM` function is not called to close it. I even added a test `alert` and I am not seeing that either.

Please help me resolve the issue.

Comment: Any errors in the console if you hit control+shift+i?

Comment: I an using IE and it opens up favorite bar :/

Comment: F12 in IE for the console. I highly recommend firefox/firebug for javascript debugging.

Comment: I am opening something from a separate updatepanel.

Comment: what about `F12` to use IE Debugger..? also I would think that with the popup along with the jquery that you would need to have a callback function to close the dialog but not sure if it works the same in jquery like it does in AngularJs

Comment: Console is blank and no error in IE

Comment: @MethodMan i am using the registerscript in code behind to call the jquery function which "should" close the popup. Even the alert function not working correctly.

Comment: instead of `Page.GetType()` it should be `typeof(Page)` I think

Comment: take a look at this example at the bottom of the page in this link how the individual registers a script as well as calling the close method 
http://forums.asp.net/t/1665707.aspx?Close+a+popup+window+which+contains+an+updatePanel+using+javascript+in+the+code+behind

Comment: @MethodMan `typeof(page)` must have done the trick and I also added them inside document.ready. Thanks.

Comment: That's a simple oversight that many overlook I've scratched my head a few times in the past when I had the same issue but when I saw your code it took me a few minutes for the light to come on again ...glad that I could quickly contribute to helping you resolve your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me that sounds very similar to this: You assign `click handlers` to `elements` which do not yet exist because the `DOM` did not finish loading yet (e.g. the `JavaScript` is initialized before your `HTML`).

I would try to attach the `click handlers` inside the `$(document).ready()` funtion, which will be called once the `DOM` is fully loaded - then the `elements` are available and they will be attached with your `handler`.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("body").on('click', "#popupContactCloseEM", function (e) {
        //e.preventDefault();
        alert('popupContactCloseEM');
        disablePopupEM();
    });
    $("body").on('click', "#backgroundPopupEM", function (e) {
        //e.preventDefault();
        alert('backgroundPopupEM');
        disablePopupEM();
    });
});
```

As you see, you only need to surround it by that `ready` function.

Comment: Thank you... I will test it out. Makes sense. One thing though, how come the PageScript function not working from the code-behind?

Comment: This worked for me along with `typeof(page)` with pagescript. Thanks.

Comment: Good to know, `typeof(page)` was suggested by @MethodMan. Glad that it's working now :-)

Comment: Yes and i think both fixed it! It was sooooo obvious but I conpletely missed it. Thanks for pointing it out.